# How can I check collision between a triangle - circle and triangle rectangle? (including rotation)

Tags: math, 2d, collision, shapes, intersect

I need to check if some shapes are colliding in a 2D world.

To check collision between circle and rectangle I found this:
[Collision Detection with Rotated Rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650032/collision-detection-with-rotated-rectangles)

But now I need to add another shape to this code (triangle), and the triangle can rotate too.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use a library. Geos, Shapely, [Jts](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html)

Comment: But in general, a rectangle and a triangle are all polygons. All you really need to know is how to intersect lines and lines, and how to intersect lines and circles.

Answer (score 0):

This JSTS example (in javascript) shows how to intersect two polygons.

https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/blob/master/examples/overlay.html

In order to modify the example to make one of them into a circle, use this snippet:

```
// this returns a JSTS polygon circle approximation with provided center and radius
function pointJSTS(center,radius){
  var point = new jsts.geom.Point(center);
  return point.buffer(radius);
}
// ....
// insert this into the example above at line 17
b = pointJSTS({x:10,y:20}, 40);
```

Further modification to the example to make the first polygon into a triangle is trivial.

Comment: Link is dead now. :(

Comment: The repo seems to have been deleted and replaced with a different version.  I found this which might help, sorry but I did not verify this:  https://github.com/Emergya/google-gis-demo/tree/master/bower_components/jsts/examples

Comment: I messaged the creator, and indeed the repo was archived, the new link is here: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/tree/0.x